# Rails:Spree:Authentication with own user table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have my own user table in my data model and I want to make the authentication for users.

I've read the authentication information at the Spree page and I followed the steps.

However I have trouble with this because it seems that the application it's working with the spree users and not my users.

Here the devise_scope on routes.rb;

```
    devise_scope :usuario do
        get '/login', :to => "devise/sessions#new"
        get '/signup', :to => "devise/registrations#new"
        delete '/logout', :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    end
```

If I comment one of this paths the login is still working...

Authentication_helpers.rb:

```
    module Spree
       module AuthenticationHelpers
         def self.included(receiver)
           receiver.send :helper_method, :spree_login_path
           receiver.send :helper_method, :spree_signup_path
           receiver.send :helper_method, :spree_logout_path
           receiver.send :helper_method, :spree_current_user
         end

       def spree_current_user
          current_usuario
       end

       def spree_login_path
          main_app.login_path
       end

       def spree_signup_path
         main_app.signup_path
       end

       def spree_logout_path
          main_app.logout_path
      end
   end
end
```

ApplicationController.send :include, Spree::AuthenticationHelpers

And spree.rb from initializers:

```
   # Configure Spree Preferences
   #
   # Note: Initializing preferences available within the Admin will overwrite any changes that were made through the user interface when you restart.
   #       If you would like users to be able to update a setting with the Admin it should NOT be set here.
   #
   # In order to initialize a setting do:
   # config.setting_name = 'new value'
   Spree.config do |config|
  # Example:
  # Uncomment to override the default site name.
       config.site_name = "Smarket"
       config.logo = "store/smarket.png"
   end

    Spree.user_class = "Usuario"

              Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
                require_dependency 'spree/authentication_helpers'
              end
```

What should I do to work with my own table and also change the signin and signup forms?

Answer (score -1):

I have just done the same on my User model as per [spree custom authentication guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/authentication.html)  without any problems.  Are you certain you followed all the steps?

As for changing the forms, the spree login is simply using the devise default login process so you would need to copy the devise forms into your app and edit them there.  See the description on [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views).